# Find a empty string value within an object and change to specific string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, object

React.

When someone is filling out a form I want to ensure that any fields they have left blank is changes to a specific string. When trying to go through an object I am getting issues...

```
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
    firstName: firstName,
    lastName: lastName,
    email: emailAddress,
  })

const personalDetails = (obj) => { 
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) { 
    // return`${key}: ${value}`
    if (value === "") { 
      return "NA"
    }
  }
}
```

When someone fails to fill in their email address I want the string 'NA' to be used in the object.

Comment: Instead of return "NA", try obj[key] = "NA"

Answer (score 0):

I think you make it too complicated. Try this one:

```
const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({
  firstName: '',
  lastName: '',
  email: '',
});
```

Use in your input placeholders.

Then:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const {firstName, ....anotherNamesFromInputs} = e.target.elements;
 // FIREBASE EXAMPLE
 firebase.firestore().collection('something').set({
  'firstName': firstName.value || firstName.placeholder, // Or as you wish 'NA'
  ...sameForOthers
 });
};


<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <label>
    Name
    <input name="firstName" placeholder="Name"/>
  </label>
  .....next labels with inputs
 <button>Sumbit</button>
</from>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `personalDetails` you wrote does not change the object properties. It just checks, if there is a key with empty string value, and if it finds one, it simply returns `"NA"` and does not change the object. It is important to mention, it returns already when it finds the first key with value `""`. Therefor, if the user does not fill `firstName`, the function returns `"NA"` and finishes its execution after `firstName`, other keys will not be checked.
So, how Madhu Magar commented, you can try something like this:

```js
if (value === "") {
  obj[key] = "NA"
}
```